# AspNet.Idendity: determine whether the user is in a specified Role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity, role-manager

I am programming an WebApp with MVC5 and I will check if a User is in a specified Role.

Therefore I have tried to use `User.IsInRole("Role")` but it throws an Exception.
I have tried with importing AspNet.Identity and using the User Manager but it can not find the method `IsInRoleAsync(userId, role)`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet;
@if(UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "Role")){
    // some code
}
```

Please notice that I use it in a cshtml file and razor syntax. I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` does not just work inside a Razor view (cshtml). You would have to instantiate an ApplicationUserManager instance, typically called "UserManager" as well as have a valid ApplicationUser ("user") object.

You are better off to do this work in the controller and pass it to the view with a View Model or other means like ViewBag or ViewData.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can easily do in view  with the following code:

**Ex: view1.cshtml**

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
     //Any code

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me. It throws a SqlServerException.